# Sending GPS coordinates between two phones

Tags: android, sockets, server, gps, tcp

I'm designing an app that requires two android phones to send their GPS coordinates to each other. I can't use bluetooth because of the potentially huge distance between the phones, and I need the phones to update each other's position very regularly. I've tried looking up what to use, but the answers I've found don't point to any useful tutorials or reference pages. I have a laptop I can use as a server if the phones can't communicate directly, but I don't know what to install or how to connect to the phones.

What should I use? Sockets? TCP/IP? Where can I find information about them? What should I use for the laptop server? Is the laptop even necessary for such a small amount of data? It doesn't need to be efficient or pretty, it just has to be easy to understand, I'm very new to this.

Comment: If your app will be installed on two specific phones and the update rate is low, consider using SMS.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to make a server to communicate b/w two or more devices. For real-time updates the best is to use XMPP server. But for beginners you can create normal RestFul web services using php, .net or any other technology.

So the flow will be like

**1st Step.** http POST Request

Device1 == Sends current location == > SERVER (saves location).

**2nd Step.** http GET Request 
Device2 == Request for Device1 location == > SERVER.

Device2 <== Response from server with Device1 location == SERVER

P.S: Getting continuous location changes need a background service to consume GPS and transmitting the location to server by making multiple calls continually will drain the device's battery very quickly